# Bucket_script aggregation on filters aggregation over nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have my documents, and they contain nested "events" (like clicks on a website) documents.

Now I want to calculate the ration between nested events with name=x and nested events with name=y

This is my query:

```
curl -XGET http://192.168.0.206:9200/user-data/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "query": { ... },
    "aggs": {
        "conversation_clicks": {
            "aggs": {
              "bucket-aggregation-for-clicks-per-conversation": {
                "filters": {
                  "filters": {
                    "presentation-clicks": { "term" : { "events.name" : "presentation-custom-anchor" }},
                    "conversation-starts": { "term" : { "events.name" : "conversation-start" }}
                  }
                }
              }, 
              "clicks-per-conversation": {
                "bucket_script": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                    "my_clicks": "bucket-aggregation-for-clicks-per-conversation['presentation-clicks']>_count", 
                    "my_conversations": "bucket-aggregation-for-clicks-per-conversation['conversation-starts']>_count"
                  },
                  "script": "params.my_clicks / params.my_conversations"
                }
              }
            },
            "nested": {
                "path": "events"
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 1
}
```

So first I create two buckets of the nested events (called "presentation-click" and "conversation-starts") This is working fine.
Now I want to divide the number of nested docs in the first bucket by the number of nested docs in the seconds bucket.

If I try this, I get this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "",
    "phase" : "fetch",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [ ],
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "class_cast_exception",
      "reason" : "class org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.nested.InternalNested cannot be cast to class org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation (org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.bucket.nested.InternalNested and org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.InternalMultiBucketAggregation are in unnamed module of loader 'app')"
    }
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

I tried to do the same calculation on non-nested documents but it also did not work. It does not raise an error, but it just doesn't do the calculation. (see my other question:  [Bucket_script aggregation on filters aggregation not showing results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187408/bucket-script-aggregation-on-filters-aggregation-not-showing-results) )

Can anyone help me understanding what the error message exactly means and how to fix my query so I get my desired result?

Thanks a lot,

Anton

---

PS: this is how a document with nested documents looks like in my index:

```
{
  "_index": "user-data",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "479951",
  "_version": 24,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "user_code": "1060",
    "team_leader": 146,
    "assistant_coach": [],
    "campaign_id": 155,
    "user_name_search": "H., Helga",
    "petitions": [],
    "team_id": 17229,
    "unfinished_donations": [],
    "campaign_name": "Puppy Love",
    "team_name": "Manfred Meier für Puppy Love",
    "id": 479951,
    "customer_name": "Demo",
    "campaign_type": null,
    "workshift_id": 7,
    "coach_id": 10020,
    "coach_name": "H., Helga",
    "campaign_is_online": true,
    "commission": null,
    "customer_id": 9,
    "events": [
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:18:55.983224+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-start",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 725,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:19:37.983224+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-start",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 726,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "conversation-start",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:19:54.983224+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 727,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-custom-anchor",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:20:31.983224+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 728,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "campaign-start-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:21:09.983224+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": "abort",
        "id": 729,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "conversation-end",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": 1.5333333333333334,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:09:14.508422+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-start",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 730,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:09:38.508422+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-start",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 731,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "conversation-start",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:10:08.508422+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 732,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-custom-anchor",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:10:47.508422+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 733,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "campaign-start-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T10:11:09.508422+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": "abort",
        "id": 734,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "conversation-end",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": 1.5166666666666666,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T19:25:35.887239+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-start",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 735,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T19:26:01.887239+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-start",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 736,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "conversation-start",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T19:26:41.887239+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 737,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-custom-anchor",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T19:27:03.887239+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 738,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "campaign-start-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T19:27:26.887239+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": "abort",
        "id": 739,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "conversation-end",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": 1.4166666666666667,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T18:37:28.683193+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-start",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 740,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T18:37:59.683193+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-start",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 741,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "conversation-start",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T18:38:48.683193+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 742,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-custom-anchor",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T18:39:13.683193+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 743,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-custom-anchor",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T18:39:39.683193+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 744,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "presentation-custom-anchor",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T18:40:21.683193+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "presentation",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 745,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "campaign-form-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T18:41:09.683193+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-form",
        "event_context_reason": "abort",
        "id": 746,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "conversation-end",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": 3.1666666666666665,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      },
      {
        "event_type": "click",
        "timestamp": "2020-04-09T18:41:46.683193+00:00",
        "event_context_source_category": "campaign-form",
        "event_context_reason": null,
        "id": 747,
        "event_context_target_id": "b3542fe3-4898-4bb3-9cb0-99a06845230e",
        "name": "campaign-start-open",
        "event_location_referrer": "/next/forms/13/start",
        "event_location_current": "/next/forms/123/form/page/page-1",
        "event_context_duration": null,
        "event_context_tag_name": "next-info-material-link",
        "event_context_source_id": "123"
      }
    ],
    "user_id": 10020,
    "campaign_name_search": "Puppy Love",
    "tags": [],
    "job_applications": [],
    "tracked_hours": 0,
    "weight": 2,
    "hours": 12,
    "campaign_manager": [
      25873
    ],
    "user_name": "H., Helga",
    "date": "2020-04-09",
    "team_type": null,
    "name": "Ganztag",
    "team_leader_name": "S., Manfred",
    "presentations": [],
    "points": 0,
    "donations": []
  },
  "fields": {
    "date": [
      "2020-04-09T00:00:00.000Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1586390400000
  ]
}
```

Comment: Lemme see a sample of your docs so it's easier to replicate.

Comment: Hey @jzzfs Thanks for you quick reply. I have added a sample document from my index.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to get rid of the `InternalNested` error is to filter w/ nested queries & perform nested `terms` aggs instead of using the `filters` aggs. It's confusing but the two are roughly the same. That way, you're isolating the nested contexts and providing the `bucket_script` with already resolved count paths.

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "all_my_documents": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "all": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "presentation-clicks": {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "events",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "events.name": "presentation-custom-anchor"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "value_count_parent": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "events"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "value_count": {
                  "value_count": {
                    "field": "events.name"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "conversation-starts": {
          "filter": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "events",
              "query": {
                "term": {
                  "events.name": "conversation-start"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "value_count_parent": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "events"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "value_count": {
                  "value_count": {
                    "field": "events.name"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "clicks-per-conversation": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "my_clicks": "presentation-clicks>value_count_parent>value_count",
              "my_conversations": "conversation-starts>value_count_parent>value_count"
            },
            "script": "params.my_clicks / params.my_conversations"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

yielding

```json
"aggregations" : {
    "all_my_documents" : {
      "buckets" : {
        "all" : {
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "conversation-starts" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "value_count_parent" : {
              "doc_count" : 4,
              "value_count" : {
                "value" : 4
              }
            }
          },
          "presentation-clicks" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "value_count_parent" : {
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "value_count" : {
                "value" : 2
              }
            }
          },
          "clicks-per-conversation" : {
            "value" : 0.5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This looks promising! Thanks! I tried it but it filters away all events in the "presentation-clicks" and "conversation-starts" sub aggregations. Need to play around with this more in the evening!

Comment: Cool. Isn't it supposed to filter precisely those two?

Comment: If you look at the sample document in the questsion. There are n nested "events" documents. Some of them have a name="presentation-custom-anchor". I want the count of them. Some have a name="conversation-start". I want the count of them.

Comment: Now I get your aggs better! It seems to work, but as "value_count" value I get 23 for both types of events. So it always counts all the events sub documents. Need to play a little more with it to count only the filtered events.